# Required fields within repeating groups FIX

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

So I am trying to generate repeating groups in a FIX message, but I need a method to determine which fields are required for each repeating group so I don't have to hard code everything. For some reason, the quickfix [DataDictionary](http://quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.3/quickfix/DataDictionary.html) class's method

```
isRequiredField((java.lang.String msgType, int field)
```

does not work for required fields within repeating groups. For example

```
isRequiredField("V", 269)
```

gives false, even thought it is [required](http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.4.2/body_505786.html). The Fix 4.2 XML also has it as required so why does the isRequiredField method return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `getGroup(java.lang.String msg, int field)`, where field is the tag for the group's counter field.

That will give you a `DataDictionary.GroupInfo` object, and on that you can call `getDataDictionary().isRequiredField(msgType,field)` (use the same message type).

I think that'll work, anyway.  The [docs](http://quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.3/) aren't explicitly clear on this.

**But why are you doing this?**

To be honest, I'm not sure why you think you need to do this.  There's simply no need to dynamically query which fields are required.  When receiving, the engine checks the required/not-required for you.  When you're sending, you have to set values to all the required fields anyway (you can't dynamically do that!).

Unless you are writing some kind of DD-analysis tool, I think you're spending your time investigating a red herring.